# Chrome Copy & Paste Bug in Windows 7 Affecting Responsive Images

Tags: html, image, google-chrome, clipboard, copy-paste

I've come across an interesting bug either in `Google Chrome`, or less likely in how `Windows 7` clipboard application.  The bug happens when performing a copy (`Ctrl+V`) on selected browser rendered CSS + HTML containing a mix of text and images and more specifically occurs when the image in this situation is coded to contain multiple copies of different sizes.  I need help verifying which app is the culprit (the browser or the clipboard) and ideally a fix if there is one (i.e. a registry edit perhaps).

There may be some security risks raised by this depending on how this behavior plays out.

---

#### Discovery

Let me begin with how I first observed this bug in `OneNote 2016`....

I sometimes save articles I come across in `OneNote` for later reading.  I'm using a locally installed `OneNote 2016` copy on `Windows 7 Enterprise SP1 (64-bit)`.  As it's an enterprise copy, the official `Web Clipper` extensions aren't an option, so I just copy the articles manually when the urge strikes.

Curiously I found that when I select a large block of text and copy and paste it, the images sometimes appear lower quality in OneNote than they do in my web browser.

As a case study, I was trying to copy this article manually: [Meet the frail, small-brained people who first trekked out of Africa](http://www.sciencemag.org/news/2016/11/meet-frail-small-brained-people-who-first-trekked-out-africa).

When copying as a block of images + formatted text (in browser: highlight the desired region, `Ctrl+C`; `Ctrl+V` in `OneNote 2016`) the image difference is immediately notable.  What I discovered is that if I `right-click` just the article image and chose `Copy image` and then paste in OneNote using specifically `right-click`, `Paste options:` > `Picture (U)` (the rightmost one), I get a much higher resolution image.

Here's an example, with the image repasted above its occurence from the original bulk paste.

[image]

Digging into the web code, I believe I've figured out why.  The issue occurs when there's multiple copies of the same image listed in some sort of variable style that I'm assuming is used to accommodate different screen resolutions or perhaps layouts specific to mobile versus PC.

The image URLs are contained in the `<img...` tag in the code below:

```
      <figure class="figure">
  <img sizes="" src="http://www.sciencemag.org/sites/default/files/styles/inline__450w__no_aspect/public/gg_61125N_FirstHumans_BottomPart.png?itok=d0BdUhJK" srcset="http://www.sciencemag.org/sites/default/files/styles/inline__450w__no_aspect/public/gg_61125N_FirstHumans_BottomPart.png?itok=d0BdUhJK 1w, http://www.sciencemag.org/sites/default/files/styles/inline__699w__no_aspect/public/gg_61125N_FirstHumans_BottomPart.png?itok=j9n6dGdk 700w" />      <figcaption>
      <div class="caption"></div>
      <div class="credit">

      Garvin Grullón  
</div>
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
```

The difference in pasted images is more glaring when it happens with vector-graphic type images, which I believe is likely the byproduct of taking the vector graphic dumped to `*.png` and then resizing it in photo-editing software by news folks (kind of defeating the point of vector graphics), hence butchering the rescaled resolution.

I show a couple instances of the overall `OneNote` copy/paste issue, below to illustrate:

[image]

---

#### Scope

Testing further I've found this bug appears to be common to all Office 2016 programs (tested on `Word 2016` and `PowerPoint 2016`) when copying blocks of text and images that contain `<img ...>` content w/ multiple URLs in the tag.

Also I discovered that when directly pasting images via the `right-click` > `Copy image` strategy, only the `Picture (U)` option in `Paste Options` pastes the correct higher res image, matching what's displayed in the browser.  `Keep Source Formatting (K)` and `Merge Formatting (M)` will interestingly still paste the lower res copy, even with this strategy.

Now the browser (`Chrome Version 54`) is displaying the proper copy, which leads me to try testing the same article and copy & paste method in `Internet Explorer 11.0`.  In `IE 11` it loads the proper highest resolution image (as so too does `Chrome Version 54`), but unlike Chrome, when bulk copying and pasting from `Internet Explorer 11` to `OneNote 2016` using that same article, magically the highest resolution image is properly pasted.

That has me thinking the bug in `Chrome` browser copy & paste.

Indeed, I may have confirmation of this, as in Adobe Pro (which is my only other locally installed rich media software with a clipboard paste option to my knowledge), choosing pasting from the clipboard (in Edit mode: `Pages` (right menu pane, second from top) > `More Insert Options` (under the `Insert Pages` section) > `Insert from Clipboard`) and then copying and pasting the image in the resulting block into `MS Paint`, I see it is indeed still the lower res image, as in `Office 2016`.

Hence I've discovered that the scope is not only `OneNote 2016` or `Office 2016`, but rather all local rich media apps including both Microsoft's own apps and third party apps from Adobe, etc.  That said, I'm still not 100% confident that I can pin the bug on `Google Chrome` as it's possible albeit perhaps less likely that the issue lies in `Windows 7`'s clipboard application, as that too would explain the universal affect on local rich media paste attempts.

Looking one more time at that `img` tag, I do see that the `srcset` `attribute` is a somewhat new attribute addition to the `img` tag which when used is termed a "[Responsive Images](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/05/responsive-images-done-right-guide-picture-srcset/)".  The feature was [announced by the W3C Working Group in 2014](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-srcset/) and per my reading most third party mobile and PC browsers claim support for it.  As I suspected is [used with CSS to target different platforms](https://css-tricks.com/responsive-images-youre-just-changing-resolutions-use-srcset/)... it appears the large dichotomy in resolution between so-called "Retina" (high-resolution) displays like those in Apple's mobile devices and low-end displays found in budget `Android` devices and budget PCs in part inspired this attribute's addition.

Humorously, the diagnostic site "Can I Use" [lists](http://caniuse.com/#search=srcset) the `img` `srcset` attribute as not working in `Internet Explorer 11` and working in `Google Chrome version 54`.  In this case the irony is that the opposite appears to be true for this use case -- `Chrome 54`'s copy is not working correctly while copying from `Internet Explorer 11` is correctly parsing the Responsive Image.

That still doesn't tell us for sure whether it's the browser or the clipboard application, but it's certainly something I find interesting to note, given that it suggests a critical missing piece of [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/)'s testing methodology (or that of whoever they get their data from -- haven't checked into that yet) as copy & paste seemingly is a common use case for rich content.

---

#### Questions

To recap and conclude, I've tracked down the scope, but the following remain unsolved questions

1. Which app is responsible -- `Windows 7`'s clipboard app or `Google Chrome`?
2. For the offending app, is there a registry setting that I can tweak to have the bulk copy and paste grab whatever image the browser is displaying?

Also, to recap the earlier thought if the bug is in `Google Chrome`, there could be some interesting security reprecussions perhaps, as you're perhaps loading URL content into the operating system's clipboard application that doesn't match the rendered content in the browser window.